# return Android Intent result back to Flutter app with MethodChannel

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I have a working app that uses [Mpv Intent](http://mpv-android.github.io/mpv-android/intent.html) to play a video, I want to return the Intent result back to flutter once the video finished or cancelled.

I'm using the example's kotlin code from the above link:

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
    call, result ->
        if (call.method == "openVideo") {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            val url = call.argument<String>("url")
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/any")
            intent.setPackage("is.xyz.mpv")
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            result.notImplemented()
        }
    }
}
```